# .htaccess rewriterule swap around url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to htaccess rewrite
old-url-part/qwerty/999-yuiop ...to... 
new-url-part/yuiop-999/qwerty

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-part/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)/?$ /new-url-part/$3-$2/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The following part works fine, but struggling with the above line

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-part/?$ /new-url-part/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the rule you need:

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-part/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ new-url-part/$2/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: He wants `999-yuiop`  to become `yuiop-999` too.

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right direction..RewriteRule ^old-url-part/([^/]+)/([0-9^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /new-url-part/$3-$2/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]